# How would a database design look like, to insert Walmart receipt information into a database?

Tags: database, ocr, erd, google-vision, tesseract.js

I am trying to design a database which will hold the information of a Grocery receipt Which will be scanned with help of OCR by Google Vision, or Tesseract .But I have no idea what kind of attributes should I use in my database, and what would the design be like. 
How many tables should I have?
What kind of relations are there going to be in between them?

I was able to find only three tables:

- Seller(ID,Name,Address, Phone),
- Product(ID,Name,Price,SellerID,IsDeleted),
- Receipt(ID,ProductID,DatePurchased,PurchaserName,PurchaserAddress)

Comment: I assume this is a homework question? Any text on database design should point you in the right direction. Choice of attributes is entirely up to what you want to store and you already have them defined in your question as far as I can see.

Comment: Could you please add a few suggestions? I added a few tables and attributes but it seems redundant data.

Comment: You need to identify what are your entities. Probably Seller, Purchaser, Product, Receipt, ReceiptLine, and then add whatever attributes you need to each, and whatever relationships you need between them. Without a full analysis of the requirements its difficult to know more.